# Activiti Reports

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I know that the Activiti Explorer integrated in the Alfresco CMS is somehow a reduced version of the full explorer available in the standalone enterprise Activiti.

I have an old installation of 4.1 on which I want to use the activiti reporting tool but I cannot find it. Is it because it wasn't available in 4.1 or because it is not available in the explorer integrated in Alfresco CMS?

Comment: Alfresco Community or Alfresco Enterprise?

Comment: It is an enterprise.

Comment: Well, Alfresco 4.1 bundles the then-latest version of Activiti, but due to the release date of 4.1 that's getting on for 3 years old now! Are you sure what you want to do is supported by Activiti 5.x?